# How do you detect which database is being used during a phpunit test?

Tags: phpunit, config, laravel-5.7

We have been having issues with local databases getting deleted while performing phpunit tests due to mistakes made in config files.  I want write a function that will check to see which database is being connected to right before a test is run, and exiting if the correct one is not being used.  How do you detect which database is being used during a phpunit test?  One situation I want to catch is when a setting has been updated, but not cached (the files look correct, but the wrong database is being used.)

I've tried `env()` and `config()` and neither give me what I am looking for.

```php
$dbconnect = DB::connection()->getPDO();
$dbname = DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
```

Throws an error.

I can open the physical `.env` and `env.testing` file and find the settings, but this does not work if the setting have not been cached correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting the wrong database during a phpunit test can be a disaster.  Doing this can destroy your real data.  Here's a simple solution: write database query early in the setUp() function that looks for real data or test data (the user table is a good target.)

Example:

`DB::table('users')->get();`

If real users are found, then you know you have the wrong database selected, and you can exit().  Also, you will want to precede this query with a check to make sure that the database in not empty.  Otherwise, the table() function will return an error.  If the database is empty, then you probably don't have a database with useful data selected.

Example:

`DB::select('SHOW TABLES');`